# Как правильно писать: Юличка или Юлечка?

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как правильно писать: *Юличка* или *Юлечка*?

Answer (score 3):

Юлечка. Уменьшительно-ласкательного суффикса -ичк- не существует

Comment: А как же слово праздничка?

Comment: Очень просто. Рассмотрим происхождение этого слова: праздник + -ек -> *праздникек -> праздничек (к чередуется с ч). Таким образом, суффикс -ечк- тут не при чем.

Comment: как раз есть суффикс ИЧК: водичка, пуговичка, ножнички!!!

Answer (score 1):

Юличка, Сашинька и т.д. ... встречаются в текстах XVIII-XIX века, приимущественно в личных письмах и заметках дружеско-фамильярного и интимного стиля. Воспринималось, видимо, как некоторый шарм.
©Грамота